# PHP search results pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am building a PHP-based search with mysql.

But I ran into this **problem**:
I have a very long and heavy (on the mysql server) query for searching.

To **paginate the results** I require the following data:

- Count of all the results (not limited, so I know how many mumbers to show)

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE col="val"
  ```
- Limited results - I show these to the user

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE col="val" LIMIT 20, 10
  ```

**How do I avoid having 2 separate queries for the 2 requirements mentioned above?**

***Notice:***
To avoid "how heavy can your query be?", this is my real where condition:

```
    SELECT *, 
    (1000 * 6371 * acos( cos( radians(42.6051862) ) * cos( radians( project_lat ) ) * cos( radians( project_lng ) - radians(23.037836800000036) ) + sin( radians(42.6051862) ) * sin( radians( project_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM `projects` 

    JOIN `subcategories` ON `projects`.`subcat_id` = `subcategories`.`subcat_id` 
    JOIN `categories` ON `subcategories`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`cat_id`
    JOIN `project_images` ON `projects`.`project_id` = `project_images`.`project_id` 

    WHERE `projects`.`subcat_id` = 618 
    AND `project_start` < '2016-10-30' 
    AND `project_start` > '2016-10-14' 
    AND `project_price` > 123 
    AND `project_price` < 233 
    AND `project_currency` = 'BTN' 
    AND `project_approved` = 1 
    AND MATCH (project_title, project_description) AGAINST ('test') 
    GROUP BY `projects`.`project_id` 
    HAVING `distance` < 7400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sql_calc_found_rows

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```